# Error reiterativo de visual studio sobre la conexión de visual con acess 2016

Tags: base-de-datos, visual-studio

He visto preguntas similares a esta y he hecho muchas cosas pero **NADA** funciona y me estoy empezando a hartar =(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que cosas probaste? porque si no, te van a dar como solucion lo mismo que probaste...

Comment: Lo que microsoft me fijo que instalase una especie de plugging para el acces de 2016

Comment: sera un controlador? y lo instalaste?

Comment: Si. Es este: https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920

Comment: y quedo bien instalado? reiniciaste? tenes permisos de administrador?

Comment: Nada. No funciona